# Why does my regex, which works in php, when encoded for .net, have encoding issues?

Tags: c#, php, regex, encoding

I'll admit, i'm not a big fan of working with regex, but I can truly appreciate what they accomplish. I also understand how they work, but long ones can baffle me.

I have a regex that is used in a PHP application I have no control over that looks like this:

```
/^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+\!\*\(\)\,\;\?\&\=\$\_\.\-]+(\:[a-z0-9+\!\*\(\)\,\;\?\&\=\$\_\.\-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9\+\$\_\-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$\_\-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$\_\-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z\+\&\$\_\.\-][a-z0-9\;\:\@\/\&\%\=\+\$\_\.\-]*)?(#[a-z\_\.\-][a-z0-9\+\$\_\.\-]*)?$/i
```

When I use an online encoding tool, or even attempt to convert the \ to \ all I end up with is an error of invalid / unrecognized encoding on _.

I do however, need to validate the URLs my service is supplying that consumes an API provided by the above PHP application. My encoded version for .net looks like this:

```
"/^(https?|ftp)\\:\\/\\/([a-z0-9+\\!\\*\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=\\$\\_\\.\\-]+(\\:[a-z0-9+\\!\\*\\(\\)\\,\\;\\?\\&\\=\\$\\_\\.\\-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9\\+\\$\\_\\-]+(\\.[a-z0-9+\\$\\_\\-]+)*(\\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\\/([a-z0-9+\\$\\_\\-]\\.?)+)*\\/?(\\?[a-z\\+\\&\\$\\_\\.\\-][a-z0-9\\;\\:\\@\\/\\&\\%\\=\\+\\$\\_\\.\\-]*)?(#[a-z\\_\\.\\-][a-z0-9\\+\\$\\_\\.\\-]*)?$/i";
```

A good example of this regex is "doesn't accept percent encoding".  Or "no spaces".  I think it's a stupid level of validation, I know how to provide a valid url, but we have some that are percent encoded due to people uploading filenames with spaces, so I have to weed them out and send automated emails... you get the gist.

Please help me figure out why this nasty regex is giving me fits in .net.

Comment: In a .NET regex, `\_` will cause an exception, remove that escape. And remove the `/` delimiters.

Comment: This website will be helpful when using Regex in .NET : http://regexstorm.net/

Comment: You don't need to escape *every* character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a string literal to avoid the double escaping and as @Wiktor points out don't escape the `_`.

```
new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+\!\*\(\)\,\;\?\&\=\$_\.\-]+(\:[a-z0-9+\!\*\(\)\,\;\?\&\=\$_\.\-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9\+\$_\-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_\-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_\-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z\+\&\$_\.\-][a-z0-9\;\:\@\/\&\%\=\+\$_\.\-]*)?(#[a-z_\.\-][a-z0-9\+\$_\.\-]*)?$", System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Comment: I always forget about string literals. Also, I didn't know you could declare it this way. Thanks.